# React, passed state is not changing in other component

Tags: reactjs

I started with react and have a small problem

```
export default function TestComponent3({ typeId}) {
    console.log('CHANGING HERE', { typeId});

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('NOT CHANGING HERE', { typeId});
    console.log('NOT CHANGING HERE EITHER', typeId);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Spectrum.Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClick}>
        CHANGING HERE {typeId}
      </Spectrum.Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

In the other component the state of 'myProp' is changing by the UI dropdown.

Spectrum.Button content changes dynamically but console logs are stuck on default state option.

I probably messed something up and and It's easy fix.

EDIT://
Sibling with a dropdown

```
export default function TypeForm({ typeId, setTypeId }) {
  return (
    <div>
        <Spectrum.Dropdown className="dropdown" placeholder="Choose type...">
          <Spectrum.Menu onChange={setTypeId} slot="options">
            {Types.map(type => { //types 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
              return (
                <Spectrum.MenuItem selected={typeId === type.id ? true : null} key={type.id} className="jsontest">
                  {type.name}
                </Spectrum.MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </Spectrum.Menu>
        </Spectrum.Dropdown>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And Parent

```
export default function Form() {
  const [typeId, setTypeId] = useState(0);

  const setTypeIdFunc = e => {
    setTypeId(e.target.selectedIndex);
  };

return (
        <TestComponent3 typeId={typeId} />
        <TypeForm
          typeId={typeId}
          setTypeId={setTypeIdFunc}
        />
)
```

Comment: Please include the parent component where you render this component and pass the prop

Comment: I add more code to the post @SinanYaman

Comment: By saying _NOT CHANGING HERE_ inside the `handleClick` function, do you mean when you click it doesn't get the latest value for `typeId`?

Comment: @SinanYaman yes, I get initial value here, but where is 'CHANGING HERE' I get current value

Comment: Well, it is not possible to get obsolete data on a mounted page with the correct value. If you can create a `codesandbox` and recreate this issue, it would be helpful.

Comment: @SinanYaman https://codesandbox.io/s/react-passed-state-is-not-changing-in-other-component-hwf49o?file=/src/TestComponent3.js

Comment: In this codesandbox example, you get the updated data when you click, no? It logs Two, One and Zero same as written on the button and the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing Spectrum.Button to normal button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The props are passed down first from the parent component of TestComponent3 during the first render.

This means you would have to send handleClick from one "higher" component. Or use a shared state-like context provider.

Comment: typeId is already in a parent component and is being passed down to its children, since is  the function `setTypeId` is passed down too, it should be able to change state from the children component (in this case `TypeForm`) and that change is reflected in whoever is using `typeId` as a prop